# WAnt to Replace EANF from much Extract iMacros

Tags: replace, eval, extract, imacros

Bellow is iMacros iim code and i want to change EXTRACT result **#EANF#** to be null or '' or change maybe to "**BRAVO**"

here is still not work any tipe EVAL code, i'm still learn `iMacros`.
And the problem is, total EXTRACT=TXT is more then 12 whic is cannot put in to !VAR1 and so on. Helps please.

```
TAB T=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:addr&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[\'#EANF#\']/,'');")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:resetForm ATTR=ID:PortalCode EXTRACT=TXT
SET EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[\"#EANF#\"]/,'');")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:addr&&TXT:*<SP>* EXTRACT=TXT
SET EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/['#EANF#']/,'');")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:info&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[\"#EANF#\"]/,'');")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:STYLE:padding-top:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[\"#EANF#\"]/,'');")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
TAB T=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:addr&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:resetForm ATTR=ID:PortalCode EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:addr&&TXT:*<SP>* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:info&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:STYLE:padding-top:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/#EANF#/g, '');")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO


TAB T=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:addr EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:resetForm ATTR=ID:PortalCode EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:addr&&TXT:*<SP>* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:info EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=STYLE:padding-top* EXTRACT=TXT

SET !EXTRACT EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace(\"#EANF#\", \"\");")
```